# Eclipse Saving file clears undo history

Tags: eclipse

I have a habit of hitting on `Ctrl+s` to save my file every now and then.  What I find with my current Eclipse setting is that once the file is saved I lose all UNDO history in the buffer --  `Ctrl+y` no longer does anything.

Is there a way to change this setting in eclipse?  I want undo history to be kept until the file is closed.

Comment: which eclipse version do you use?

Comment: I'm using Zend Studio 8.0. I believe it is built on eclipse 3.6.x

Comment: so I'm using also Eclipse Helios and Undo-History does not get lost on save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Save Actions. A specific action on save may be defined to clear the editing history.

Comment: Can't seem to find the preference "Clear undo buffer on save" or anything like that in my current version of eclipse.

Comment: is your history lost when you press File->Save from the toolbar or is it just related to keyboard shortcut of save action. If File->Save works correctly, you should check Window->Preferences->General->Keys and the binding of ctrl+s shortcut.

Answer (score 6):

We have just found a similar situation where the undo history wasn't available anymore after saving. The reason seemes to be that the editor has been "crashed" and doesn't work anymore as expected. The solution is to simply close the editor tab and reopen the file in a new editor.